# Setting one program not to require admin rights

Tags: administrator

I have set up a work laptop which is to be handed over to an employee.

I have put their printer software on the machine ready to install but cannot complete at my end as the printer is at their house.

To install the software properly they would currently need to enter the administrator password which I would not want to give them.

Is there any way to remove the admin password requirement for this 1 program?

Comment: Windows? Linux?

Comment: You don't need Administrator rights to add a printer nor do you need the OEM software distributed by most printer manufactures.  Worst case, you write instructions, on how to use the single .inf file for the printer.

Comment: @John - I never said all printers, I said most printers, and I have never encountered a printer that could not be installed with just the .inf file.  *I did not downvote your deleted answer by the way.*